# Get Body of a Message - Java

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm not really understanding the Apache Camel documentation.

I have a from where I want to call a java function and get the body of the message.

I think the route is missing something. How does it know where the function is?

```
// I get a message from my email and I want to send to the bean
<to uri="bean:doSomething"/>
```

CamelTest

```
public class CamelTest {

@Bean
public void doSomething() {
    How do I get the body?
}
}
```

Error:

> org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean could be found in the
>   registry for: doSomething

Comment: "I have a from..." -> You have a what ? I don't know about Apache Camel, but your error seems to be a beginner problem that can be solved by looking for "How to declare bean in apache camel ?"

Comment: Once you solve bean problem, you can get body by adding the parameter @Body in your method
e.g. public void doSomething(@Body String body){...}

Type of body in my example is String, you have to add the body type you should expect (Object, String, CustomObject, List<..>, etc)

Answer (score 0):

HI user10717851 make sure you have declared your bean in bean.xml and refer this bean.xml in camel-context.xml which will resolve this issue.